# Using framework event dispatcher to raise domain event

Tags: php, events, laravel, domain-driven-design, dispatcher

When i need to raise domain events, should i use framework specific Event Dispatcher or create my own Event Dispatcher that implemented by framework event dispatcher ?
Since the framework has a really nice event dispatcher and the term of DDD said the domain layer should not dependent on any external thing, i got confused. :D

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately I favor returning events from domain methods and handling those in the application service layer.  Since the application service layer is where you bring together all kinds of infrastructure further processing of the returned events, such as dispatching, can be handled in the application service layer.

In this way you do not need to use a dispatcher singleton or pass in any reference to a dispatcher to your domain.

Comment: Lovely answer.
So the application service layer has the responsibility to keep eventual consistency, right ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the application service has the responsibility to keep eventual consistency, no.  However, if you are using events with a messaging system the events will, well, eventually be processed resulting in your consistency :) --- so no specific part of your system is responsible for the eventual consistency, it is rather a result of the completion of all processing at some future point in time.  The application service is, however, responsible for dispatching the events and guaranteeing transactional consistency.

Answer (score 0):

It's a design choice. If you want to add additional functionality to the event dispatcher or expect to be doing that soon, extend. Otherwise if you implement that exact functionality, just use the class. There is no need to extend classes and you will be always able to do so once the need arrives.

Comment: I mean, is it really need to fully decouple domain layer from framework ?

Comment: No. In the end it's the developers' decision.

Answer (score 0):

what i do is have my aggregate record a list of events that happen during a business transaction and within my application service i publish the event like this:

```
        IDomainEventPublisher publisher = new DomainEventPublisher();
        publisher
            .SubscribeTo<ConsigneeCreated>()
                .UsingDelegate(e =>
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Consignee Id - {0}", e.ConsigneeId.ToString())));


        publisher.Publish(consignee.ReleaseEvents());
```

Comment: Lovely answer.
So the application service layer has the responsibility to keep eventual consistency, right ?